# Cannot log in to chat

Tags: support, chat

Can someone tell me why I'm getting an error saying my login information seems too old when I try to log in to chat?

Comment: Can you try using this link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning (Let's try to troubleshoot this through)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this link?

http://chat.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Thanks, I think it was the firewall at work.